Write a df from a Microsoft Fabric notebook into my local disk folder
How do I write a dataframe in my microsoft fabric notebook to a folder in my local computer as an excel file.
I have tried but I keep getting that folder directory does not exits.I have checked the local folder directory does exists.
If there is any work around, I would appreciate.
Thank you
Here is the example of the code below
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd

# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SaveDFtoExcel").getOrCreate()

# Create a sample PySpark DataFrame
data = [("Alice", 34), ("Bob", 45), ("Catherine", 29)]
columns = ["Name", "Age"]
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

# Convert PySpark DataFrame to Pandas DataFrame
pandas_df = spark_df.toPandas()

# the local file path
file_path = "C:/Users/YourUsername/Documents/sample_data.xlsx"

# Save the Pandas DataFrame to an Excel file
pandas_df.to_excel(file_path, index=False, engine="openpyxl")

Here is error message
OSError: Cannot save file into a non-existent directory: 'C:/Users/YourUsername/Documents/sample_data.xlsx'

I am very confident that the file directory exists and it is correct and I have permission to write and read into that directory.
It worked in my normal positron or VScode IDE but does not work in the Microsoft Fabric Notebook
Thank you.

Can you add your code and error that you are getting?
